# PostgreSQL replication

Tags: postgresql, replication, postgresql-9.1

I have two projects working on different databases. The problem is: I need to replicate changes in the databases only for a few tables. I need it to synchronize the data.
Need an advice how can I solve it.
I have PostgreSQL 9.1 DB servers, the replication schema is master-master. What I found is:

1. [Rubyrep](http://www.rubyrep.org/)
2. [Bucardo](http://bucardo.org/)
3. [Postgres-XC](http://postgres-xc.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Use Bucardo.
Slony is great for master-slave replication, also it doesn't have an option for master-master.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to replicate only a few tables master-master, then Bucardo is probably your best bet.

Comment: Bucardo++.  Otherwise I'd look at using some kind of cross database replication with slony.